# Implement JOIN with several tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I have this table from which I would like to select many rows and use JOIN in order to translate id to name from two tables. I tried this:

Main table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_transactions")
public class PaymentTransactions implements Serializable {
    ..... 
    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer merchant_id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer terminal_id; 
    ......
}
```

Table with additional data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "merchants")
public class Merchants implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;
    .........
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "terminals")
public class Terminals implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;
    .........
}
```

I tried this:

```
String hql = "select e.* from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e "
                + " INNER JOIN " + Merchants.class.getName() + " m "
                + " ON e.id = m.merchant_id AND " 
                + " INNER JOIN " + Terminals.class.getName() + " t "
                + " ON e.id = t.terminal_id "
                + " where e.created_at >= :start_date and e.created_at <= :end_date";
```

The general idea is that I want to have one main table `Payment transactions` which stores `merchant_id` and `terminal_id` as numbers. With join I want to get the name of the Merchant and Terminal. What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add those variables to the column list in your query:

```
String hql = "select e.*, m.name AS merchant, t.name AS terminal"
                + " FROM " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e "
                + " INNER JOIN " + Merchants.class.getName() + " m "
                + " ON e.id = m.merchant_id AND " 
                + " INNER JOIN " + Terminals.class.getName() + " t "
                + " ON e.id = t.terminal_id "
                + " where e.created_at >= :start_date and e.created_at <= :end_date";
```

Note you will need to add column aliases to avoid having the same column name (`name`) twice in the output result. The query includes these (e.g. `m.name AS merchant`) so you can access the merchant name as the `merchant` column when you fetch results.

Comment: Using `AS` keyword, just as it is shown in this example `select e.*, m.name AS merchant`, where `merchant` is the alias

Comment: @PeterPenzov I've already put the column aliases in the query (`m.name AS merchant`)